# In Java, how do you loop through a string and check if it contains the keys in a hash map?

Tags: java

The goal is to write a text message abbreviation expander program that takes a string and checks for common abbreviations like LOL, IDK, etc. and replace them with the full length sentence, laugh out loud, I don't know, etc.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TextMsgExpander {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter text: ");
    String userInput = scnr.nextLine();
    System.out.println("You entered: " + userInput);

    // Create new instance of Hash Map
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    //Key value pairs
    map.put("LOL", "laugh out loud");
    map.put("IDK", "I don't know");
    map.put("BFF", "best friend forever");
    map.put("TTYL", "talk to you later");
    map.put("JK", "just kidding");
    map.put("TMI", "too much information");
    map.put("IMHO", "in my humble opinion");

    //Access points
    String LOL = map.get("LOL");
    String IDK = map.get("IDK");
    String BFF = map.get("BFF");
    String TTYL = map.get("TTYL");
    String JK = map.get("JK");
    String TMI = map.get("TMI");
    String IMHO = map.get("IMHO");

    System.out.println(TMI);

    // While user input contains any of the keys, replace keys with
    // values.
    return;
  }
 }
```

Comment: I would simply use userInput.replace("LOL", "laugh out loud"); and so on

Comment: What if the text has the word "KILOLITRES"? Should it become KIlaugh out loudITRES"? A simple, though not foolproof way to deal with that is to add a space character to the beginning and end of your source string, and then search for words with space at each end as in `" LOL "`.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instead iterate(loop) over the complete set of keys and look for them in the `userInput`, if they are present replace them with the respective value from the map as :

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (userInput.contains(entry.getKey())) {
        userInput = userInput.replaceAll(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}
System.out.println("Converted string  - " + userInput);
```